# Unchecking a "checked cell"

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have created a simple tableview where you can check off task that are completed. The code for this specific property looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let mySelectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    mySelectedCell.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()


}
```

The problem is that I can not uncheck these cells once they are checked. Does anyone know how this property is added?

Any thoughts on how to proceed would be appreciated.

EDIT: I now know that there is a need for an if-statement, but I do not know how to check if my cell has already been checked.

Comment: Have you implemented didDeselectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but if you're talking about implementing the override function "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" then yes, I have.

Comment: `mySelectedCell.accessoryType = .None`...?

Comment: Lyndsey: Sorry, I thought you meant the override function I already have posted. What other "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" functions are there?

Comment: did*De*selectRowAtIndexPath As it says in the docs, "The [didDeselectRowAtIndexPath] delegate handles row deselections in this method. It could, for example, remove the check-mark image (UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) associated with the row." https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Lyndsey: Sorry, I thought you meant the override function I already have posted. What other "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" functions are there?

Comment: Lyndsey: Ok, now I saw what you actually wrote. I'll try that out :)

Comment: You need to store your cell checked status in your data model. You cannot use the cell itself for state tracking because of cell reuse when the table scrolls.

Comment: @Paulw11 I guess I'll have to dig deeper into data models then, it had to be done sooner or later, I guess. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do a simple on an off for aesthetics only...

```
if (mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark) {
    mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
}
else {
    mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}
```

If you want to do it based on a property...

```
if (!myValue[indexPath.row].value) { // if the BOOL is NO
    mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
}
else {
    mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}
```

Comment: Great, just one question: When I use these if-statements, it says that "type '()' does not conform to protocol 'Boolean Type'". Do you know why this is?

Comment: @frank21 I'm an Objective-C guy, only played around with Swift but you might try `if (myObject[indexPath.row).value == NO)` That may something Swift enforces. Also check to make sure you're using a boolean property.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been very helpful!

Comment: @frank21 Glad I was of some help. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can't uncheck it because it's assigning the checkmark every time it's called rather than alternating. Use an if statement to see if its checked and switch between accessory types checkmark and none.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, but how do you check if a cell is already checked?